# Reference request: hedge fund strategies

Tags: reference-request, hedge-fund

I am looking for a survey book on general hedge fund strategies, preferably on the quantitaitive side. An ideal book would survey common hedge fund strategies (e.g. fixed income arb, volatility arb) and be somewhat on the technical side.

Comment: "Expected Returns" by Ilmanen may not be exactly that, but worth having a look.

Comment: Very few people know both Fixed Income Arb and [Equity] Volatility Arb, so unless john meriwether writes a book...

Comment: @noob2, since you mentioned FI - what are top quant funds, that specialize in FI? Or for FI being "quant" is not so well defined, as, say, for equities?

Comment: @noob2 If John Meriwether wrote a book it’s not completely clear that one should follow any of the advice in it...

Answer (score 1):

"Active Equity Management" gives a decent coverage for US equities.

[https://www.amazon.com/Active-Equity-Management-Xinfeng-Zhou/dp/0692297774/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510952220&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=active+portfolio+management+quantitative+theory+and+applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0692297774)

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend most recent aggregation of the literature on hedge funds (or Alternative Investment Vehicles). It's very useful and considers all topics related to hedge funds performance/performance persistence and their statistical properties:

```
"Recent advances in hedge funds' performance attribution: Performance
persistence and fundamental factors"
```

by `Dimitrios Stafylas, Keith Anderson, Moshfique Uddin`

Published in the `International Review of Financial Analysis` [highly respected 3 star journal]

You can find it [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1057521915001714)

Comment: This does not really answer the question which is not about performance attribution but about the strategies themselves.

Comment: Please respect the be nice policy.